# How Do I Fix This For Loop in This Array?

Tags: java, arrays

Here are the instructions for the assignment: "Array testGrades contains NUM_VALS test scores. Write a for loop that sets sumExtra to the total extra credit received. Full credit is 100, so anything over 100 is extra credit. Ex: If testGrades = {101, 83, 107, 90}, then sumExtra = 8, because 1 + 0 + 7 + 0 is 8."
The program almost works except for when this input is entered: {101, 110, 103, 100}. Instead of yielding 14 (1 + 10 + 3 = 14), it yields 4. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfExcess {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int NUM_VALS = 4;
      int[] testGrades = new int[NUM_VALS];
      int i;
      int sumExtra = -9999; // Assign sumExtra with 0 before your for loop

      for (i = 0; i < testGrades.length; ++i) {
         testGrades[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      /* Your solution goes here  */
      sumExtra = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < testGrades.length; ++i) {
        if (testGrades[i] >= 101) {
            sumExtra = testGrades[i] - 100;  
            ++sumExtra;
        }
     }

  System.out.println("sumExtra: " + sumExtra);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix your title so in the future when you again face the same kind of problem as here you would be able to find precisely this question easily? Otherwise this defeats the purpose of this site, which is to be *searchable* repository of programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning sumExtra each time. So you would want to instead use
`sumExtra += testGrades[i-100];` and get rid of `++sumExtra;`

Answer (score 0):

You should not do:

```
++sumExtra;
```

and you should sum here:

```
sumExtra += testGrades[i] - 100;
```

Final code:

```
sumExtra = 0;
for (i = 0; i < testGrades.length; ++i) {
    if (testGrades[i] >= 101) {
        sumExtra += testGrades[i] - 100;  
    }
}
```